# Android: Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

When `frButton` is clicked `FragmentOne` should open and `MainActivity` should be hidden but Components of `MainActivity` is still accessible in `FragmentOne`, which is unwanted.
How to fix it?

**code for MainActivity:**

```
public void gofag1(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FragmentOne frag = new FragmentOne();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // import
    FragmentTransaction ftr = fm.beginTransaction(); // import
    ftr.add(R.id.mainlayout, frag, "keyFrag");
    ftr.addToBackStack(null);
    ftr.commit();
}
```

**code for FragmentOne:**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

public FragmentOne() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,
            false);
    return v;
}
}
```

**code for FragmentOne layout... R.layout.fragment_one**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.megavb.le.FragmentOne" >

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tOnOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/a1" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="reedToggleValue"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

**code for MainActivity layout.... R.id.mainlayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="gofag1"
    android:text="fOne" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please see the picture for better understanding...

[image: PICTURE HERE]

Comment: Please post the layout file for `R.layout.fragment_one`

Comment: R.layout.fragment_one submitted in main message

Comment: Is `R.id.mainlayout` a reference to a `FrameLayout`?

Comment: No to Relative layout...does it have to be Frame Layout?

Answer (score 3):

So, you should be using `ftr.replace` instead of `ftr.add`

```
public void gofag1(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FragmentOne frag = new FragmentOne();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // import
    FragmentTransaction ftr = fm.beginTransaction(); // import

    //Notice the change here
    ftr.replace(R.id.mainlayout, frag, "keyFrag");
    ftr.addToBackStack(null);
    ftr.commit();
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Well, without more information I'm going to take another stab at this.

In your `mainlayout.xml` you need to define a Fragment Container a simple method of doing this would be to use a layout file like the one that follows as a base for your Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
</FrameLayout>
```

after defining this new fragment container you can programmatically add fragments to it by referencing it's ID.

The next step is to move your original MainActivty code into a new fragment!

This is the code for `fragment_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="gofag1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here we create a new layout that simply contains a button.

Next we create the actual fragment

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

    public FragmentMain() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
}
```

From here we can change our Main activity `OnCreate` code to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
    FragmentMain frag = new FragmentMain();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // import
    FragmentTransaction ftr = fm.beginTransaction(); // import
    ftr.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag, "keyFrag");
    ftr.addToBackStack(null);
    ftr.commit();


}
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your `mainlayout.xml` please?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); instead of ftr.addToBackStack(null);  ??? but it throws error!

Comment: sorry about that i took that line from one of my programs, i changed it to match your variable!

Comment: But..........this is the same code which I have posted except...FragmentONe is renamed to FragmentMain....and android:id="@+id/mainlayout"  to  android:id="@+id/fragment_container"... it does not solve the prob...   :((

Comment: Read through it one more time and looks at all of the changes. You need to change code in your main activity so that it loads a fragment into the container instead of loading in a set layout. This allows you to replace the fragment dynamically.

Comment: ....I can see..what you are trying to do...But I must have Buttons on Activity ...meaning MainActivity view must be loaded and Only when the Button on MainActivity is clicked then and then transfer to FragmentOne should be possible..Not directly loading FragmentOne inside MainActivity!!!!

Comment: ...Does the container has to be Frame layout? or can it be Relative layout?

Comment: I think you may be trying to create a new activity then rather than a fragment, This code should do exactly what you stated you needed in the Question.

Comment: There is no reason to use a `RelativeLayout` in this example as all you are doing is populating the entire thing with a new `Fragment` whenever the button is pressed. It by no means has to be a `FrameLayout` but it does not make sense to use a more complex `RelativeLayout` whenever the functionality it provides is not used.

Comment: Can you please post Fragment Layout file as well? I can see only one instance for button rather than two...I need two Buttons...one in MainActivity and the other in FragmentOne... both the Buttons have different purpose and different onClick functions/methods..

Comment: Which fragment layout file? i posted the one for `FragmentMain` and the one for `FragmentOne` you should have already.

Comment: bit confusing...we need two buttons (one in each xml file)...the layout files you have posted has only one button in two files together!

Comment: So, you actually need three layout files. One is called main_layout this contains the layout that contains the fragment container.  The next is for your first Fragment, the one with a single button that when you click, takes you to the other fragment, this is called `fragment_main` . Last, you have your other fragment, `FragmentOne` which is another layout file.  So, to recap, I have posted `FragmentMain` aka `fragment_main` and `main_layout`. one is a layout for a fragment, the other is a fragment container. The other one that you are looking for you already have the code to that you wrote.